# facebook sdk 3.1-ios compatible with ios 5.1 -5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, ios5.1

regards

I have an application that uses the Facebook API for certain features This application should run both 5.1 and 6 ios 5 my question is the Facebook API 3.1 is compatible with iOS 5 and 5.1 thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is compatible. Just mark the iOS6 only frameworks as optional to get it working.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of how you do that.
[image]

Comment: ohh!..ok thank you very much  but then just add the framework 3.1 and this will serve me for all versions of IOS mentioned?

Comment: There's one more optional framework to add, Social.framework.